# How to locate and extract the logic behind an invoked function or method in Rust?

Tags: function, rust, rust-proc-macros

I am trying to build an auto-differentiation procedural macro in Rust. Currently, the macro can successfully evaluate the partial derivative of a given expression when all of the logic is contained within the bounds of the macro. However, when attempting to evaluate a function or method call to logic that has been previously defined the system runs into an issue as these items fail to contain all of the information required to successfully compute the partial derivative.

#### Questions

- Is it possible to create a function that can locate and extract the body of a function or implemented method call using the rust compiler or some other similar method?

After doing some research, it seems the `rustdoc` crate has an experimental feature (`scrape_examples`) which essentially finds all of the relevant function calls found in any examples. I am considering creating a modified version of this to fit my needs, however, would prefer to find a less invasive and more streamlined approach to solving the issue.

#### Working Examples

```rust
use acme::prelude::autodiff;

fn main() {
    let x = 2_f64;
    assert_eq!(autodiff!(x: 1.0 / (1.0 + (-x).exp())), sigmoid_prime(x));
    assert_eq!(
        autodiff!(x: | x: f64 | 1.0 / (1.0 + (-x).exp())),
        sigmoid_prime(x)
    );
    assert_eq!(
        autodiff!(x: fn sigmoid(x: f64) -> f64 { 1_f64 / (1_f64 + (-x).exp()) }),
        sigmoid_prime(x)
    );
}
```

#### Objective

```rust
use acme::prelude::{autodiff, sigmoid};

fn main() {
    let x = 2_f64;
    assert_ne!(autodiff!(x: sigmoid(x)), sigmoid_prime(x));

}
```

Comment: To my knowledge, no, Rust macros cannot introspect entities they don't contain or are not attached to.

Comment: The information about which function calls refer to which function definitions is not known when macros are expanded since that can change depending on what macros do. However, you can have your macro register things globally that you can then use like they're functions in other macro invocations. So you would have `autodiff!(x: sigmoid(x))` look for info from the previous macro call `autodiff!(x: fn sigmoid(x: f64) ...)`.

Comment: @drewtato Thank you; this process aligns with an alternative approach I’ve considered which uses proc_macro_attributes, I was just curious to see if the optimal behavior was even possible. I also suppose that it would be either too clumsy, slow, and/or impossible to interrupt the compiler after resolving the function definition and quickly re-evaluate the body.

Comment: Are there any on-going efforts that may end up solving this problem in the future or is this just a limitation of Rust?

Comment: The timing of macro expansion is pretty solid, so I don't expect that to ever change. It is possible that in the future you'll be able to name specific function types, which would let you attach traits to them, which may help with the macro method. But that's pretty long-term.

Comment: @drewtato Are there any concerns with that approach in the context of incremental compilation? I've been steered away from using anything like that in macros in other languages due to the macro code only running when the unit is compiled, so I'm surprised to hear it recommended here.

Comment: @EdwardPeters That's true, I forgot about that. It should still be possible, but you need to `include_bytes` the right files and ensure your macros work in any order.